# Break database field into words

Tags: php, sql

In my database I have a "willingness" field with a value like: sports,pub,drink,drive,smile etc.

When do this in my template:

```
<? echo '<p>'.$willingness.'</p>'; ?>
```

I get a string: sports,pub,drink,drive,smile
How can I break this into words  like: sports, pub, drink, drive, smile?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://php.net/explode

```
$arrayWillingness = explode(",", $willingness);

echo $arrayWillingness[0]; //sports
echo $arrayWillingness[1]; //pub
echo $arrayWillingness[2]; //drink
echo $arrayWillingness[3]; //drive
echo $arrayWillingness[4]; //smile
```

If you're using it in a loop:

```
$arrayWillingness = explode(",", $willingness);

foreach ($arrayWillingness as $value) {
     echo $value;
}
```

Comment: yes but willingness number of words differs. I use it in a loop.

Comment: Updated my answer, you can use the foreach construct.